# How to make virtual key small later?

Tags: java, robocode

How to make small vk letters like case VK_k instead of VK_K?
using Switch Case 
Thanks

```
public void onKeyPressed(KeyEvent e){

    switch(e.getKeyCode()){

    case VK_K: 
               moveDirection=1;
               moveAmount = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

             break;

    case VK_L: moveDirection=-1;
               moveAmount = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
             break;

    case VK_H: turnDirection=-1;
             break;

    case VK_J: turnDirection=1;
             break;
    case VK_SPACE: firePower = 1;
            break;

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: `VX_*` will match lower case or uppercase.  In fact it has nothing to do with the case.  It has to do with the actual button press.

Comment: It's for a Robocode Project. The Robocode should move by pressing small letters

Answer (score 4):

You should read the description of [KeyEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyModifiersText(int)) fully - it contains the answer:

> Virtual key codes are used to report which keyboard key has been pressed, rather than a character generated by the combination of one or more keystrokes (such as "A", which comes from shift and "a").

Conclusion: Your keyboard has only one `K` key - hence there is only the constant `VK_K`. What other keys (shift, alt, ctrl, ..) you are pressing at the same time does not change the key code you get.

Comment: Ok,may its not possible, but what can I use to fix that? while loop?

Iam a beginner, i must say :D

Comment: @NL_FH fix what? What is there to "fix"?